# Collation Problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation, database-schema

Im getting different  collation in different objects in a database...

- Collation of Tables is 'SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS'
- Collation of Stored Procedure is 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'

Which is creating problem while executing query.
Can someone help me out?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What's the problem you are experiencing? Do you have a question to go with this?

Comment: ''Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the like operation.'' ..this is the error message im getting while executing a stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to specify according to which collation you wish to do the join (or where clause)

See the example below on how to code this.

```
create table x( id int, name varchar(256) collate SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS)
create table y( id int, name varchar(256) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)

insert into x values (1, 'Filip')
insert into y values (1, 'Filip')
```

So if you wish to join based on Latin1 collation you write the query like this:

```
select * 
  from x
  join y 
    on x.name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = y.name
```

If you wish to join based on Swedish collation you write the query like this:

```
select * 
  from x
  join y 
    on x.name = y.name collate SQL_SwedishStd_Pref_CP1_CI_AS
```

If the collation difference has been created by incorrectly defining the table you can alter the column to switch the collation:

```
alter table x alter column name varchar(256) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

If you then run the query like this, no more errors will occur:

```
select * 
  from x
  join y 
    on x.name = y.name
```